# How to simply send current selected DataGridRow item to ICommand in ViewModel on double click

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to send the current selected `DataGridRow` to a double-click `InputBinding`?

I have this in my view

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Consignments}" 
            x:Name="dataGridConsignments" 
            Margin="10,47,10,9.6"
            IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            xmlns:DataGridDoubleClickCommand="{Binding DataGridDoubleClick}">
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"  Command="{Binding RowDoubleClick}"/>
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>

...
```

And the viewModel contains

```
private ICommand rowDoubleClick;
public ICommand RowDoubleClick
{
    get
    {
        return rowDoubleClick
            ?? (rowDoubleClick= new ActionCommand(() =>
            {
                // I need the selected row here
                MessageBox.Show("asd");
            }));
    }
}
```

With This `ActionCommand` implementation:

```
public class ActionCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;

    public ActionCommand(Action action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `CommandParameter`.

```
<MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding RowDoubleClick}"
   CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=dataGridConsignments, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
```

Doing this will require you to implement the `ICommand` interface such that your `Action` takes a parameter. You can see a standard implementation and usage of `RelayCommand` [here](https://gist.github.com/schuster-rainer/2648922). It is very similar to what you did for `ActionCommand`, but it allows for a parameter that you can use in your code.

Alternatively, you can simply bind the `SelectedItem` of your `DataGrid` to a property in your View Model, and use that when the command fires.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Consignments}" SelectedItem="{Binding VMSelectedItem}" ../>
```

For either of the approaches, keep in mind that if there are no selected items in the `DataGrid`, the selected item will be `null`, so you will need to do a null check before operating on the property/parameter.

Comment: Do you know how I can bind all selected items?

Comment: I don't believe you can directly two-way bind to `SelectedItems`, as it is a read-only property. I have accomplished this goal in two ways in the past. 1) Use `CommandParameter` to pass `SelectedItems` rather than `SelectedItem` with command binding as above. 2) Use `InteractionTriggers` to update the selected items in your VM whenever selection changes. If you'd like, I can add this two my answer with some code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by adding this line to the DataGrid

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Consignments}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedConsignment}"
```

Keep in mind to notify the "OnPropertyChanged".

Comment: what happens if the SelectedConsignment property is set to null?

Comment: You need to check if the SelectedConsignment is null inside the code. Simple if(SelectedConsignment!=null){} or try catch would do the work.

Comment: Does the DataGrid must be ReadOnly?

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be ReadOnly. It depends on your needs.